# how to select each image uniquely in android using appium

Tags: android, image, appium

Hi i am new on automating mobile apps, some help would be appreciated. 
i want to select some images from gallery through app, however all the images are having same class name and i can select only one image, while trying to select other image it just deselects first image and select that image again.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='pictures']")).click();  //image selection // select folder 

if(Product.equalsIgnoreCase("Photobooks"))
{
    // number of images to be selected is equal to 
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ImageView")).click();


    }
```

This code goes clicks on one folder containing images and tries to selelct 40 images from the gallery to design book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep finding the same element.

What you need to do is to get the list of ALL the images, and then click on every image from that list:

```
List<WebElement> imageList = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.ImageView")).click();
    if(Product.equalsIgnoreCase("Photobooks"))
        {
            // number of images to be selected is equal to 
            for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
                imageList.get(i).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
}
```

Comment: i tried with the above code but it select each image and deselect the previous and selects the new one. how can it select all the images by not deselecting the previously clicked one.

Comment: How does the app work? do you need to Long press the first image to start multi-selection? Does there an icon that you need to press that enables multi-selection? This is your part to do, I just helped you with Coding + Appium basics